# Address already in use when run kafka connect distributed mode

Tags: distributed, apache-kafka-connect

I launched confluent suite by issue "./bin/confluent start" command.
Then I use kafka connect to sink kafka data into mysql.

I can run kafka connect well in standalone mode by executing the following command:

> ./bin/connect-standalone
>   ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties
>   ./etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/adstats-jdbc-sink.properties

Then I close above command and switch to distributed mode by command:

> ./bin/connect-distributed
>   ./etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties
>   ./etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/adstats-jdbc-sink.properties

It reported the following exception:

> [2018-08-09 14:51:56,951] ERROR Failed to start Connect
>   (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:108)
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Unable to start REST
>   server    at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.RestServer.start(RestServer.java:214)
>     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Connect.start(Connect.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed.main(ConnectDistributed.java:106)
>   Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)

What's wrong? How can I switch to use kafka connect distributed mode? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When you run `confluent start` you already started Kafka Connect in distributed mode. So you can either use that instance, or you can define a new REST port in the properties file for the second instance that you want to run.

Either way, you submit your sink configuration to Kafka Connect distributed over REST, rather than passing it as a properties argument at start up (unlike standalone).

Answer (score 0):

After bootstrapping all the confluent services via

```
./confluent start
```

make sure to stop default kafka-connect through

```
./confluent stop connect
```

before starting your customized kafka-connect.